# Individual profile pages and searches Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, search, routes, profile

Having a real confusing time with this project, my issue is I'm trying to get my search working but for some reason its not pulling results from my query when there is that information in the database, also when I click on the username in the top corner of my page, it should redirect to the user page but instead I get this error "NotFoundHttpException in Application.php line 879:" with the URl looking like this "http://localhost/WorldLink/users/firstName%20=%3E%20Auth::user%28%29-%3EfirstName" and I have exhausted all other means of trying to fix it so I'm back for some help! my code is below Im using laravel 5.2:

Users.php

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Users extends Model
{   
protected $table = 'users';

protected $fillable = [
    'id', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'bio', 'homeLocation', 'currentLocation', 'email', 'password',
];

public function getName()
{
    if ($this->firstName && $this->lastName) {
        return "{$this->firstName} {$this->lastName}";
    }

    if ($this->firstName) {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    return null;
}

public function getNameOrLocation()
{
    return $this->getName() ?: $this->currentLocation;
}

public function getFirstNameOrLocation()
{
    return $this->firstName ?: $this->currentLocation;
}

public function getAllAvatarsUrl()
{
    return "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{ md5($this->email) }}?d=mm&s=40";
}
}
```

SearchController.php:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB;
use App\Users;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SearchController extends BaseController
{
public function getResults(Request $request)
{   
    $query = $request->input('query');

    if (!$query) {
        return back();
    }

    $users = Users::where(DB::raw("CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName)"), '
        LIKE', "%{$query}%")
        ->orWhere('currentLocation', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")
        ->get();

    return view('search/results')->with('users', $users);
}
```

ProfileController.php

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProfileController extends BaseController
{
public function getProfile($firstName)
{       
    $users = User::where('firstName', $firstName)->first();

    if (!$users) {
        abort(404);
    }

    return view('profile.index')
        ->with('users', $users);

}
}
```

userblock.blade.php

```
<div class="media">
<a class="pull-left" href="{{ route('profile/index', ['firstName' => $users->firstName]) }}">
    <img class="media-object" alt="{{ $users-getNameOrLocation() }}" src="{{ $users->getAllAvatarsUrl() }}">
</a>
<div class="media-body">
    <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="{{ route('profile/index', ['firstName' => $users->firstName]) }}">{{ $users->getNameOrLocation() }}</a></h4>
</div>
@if ($users->currentLocation)
    <p>{{ $users->currentLocation }}</p>
@endif
```

results.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
  <h3>Search Results for "{{ Request::input('query') }}"</h3>

  @if (!$users->count())
    <p>No Results Found</p>
  @else
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            @foreach ($users as $user)
              @include('users/partials/userblock')
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
  @endif
@endsection
```

And finally my two routes, the problem is connected in here somewhere I just cant find where its going wrong.

```
    Route::get('/search', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\SearchController@getResults',
    'as' => 'search/results',
]);

Route::get('/users/{firstName}', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@getProfile',
    'as' => 'profile/index',
]);
```

The Link:

```
         @if (Auth::guest())
                    <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></li>
                @else
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" action="{{ route('search/results') }}">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="query">
                        </form>
                        <li><a href="{{ route('profile/index', ['firstName => Auth::user()->firstName']) }}">{{ Auth::user()->firstName }}</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Timeline</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/link') }}">Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/journeys') }}">Journeys <span class="journey-num">{{ Auth::user()->journeys }}</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/forum') }}">Forum</a></li>
                    </ul>
```

Comment: The uri looks wrong to start with seems to have the Auth class in there. Where is the code to make the link?

Comment: Sorry! Added that in at the bottom now! :)

Comment: Yeah I think you have some problem with your string there it's just printing out the command url encoded. Check your quotation pairs

Comment: I've checked the quote pairs and can't find anything off, its a weird one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defo quoting incorrectly

```
.... 
<li><a href="{{ route('profile/index', ['firstName' =>Auth::user()->firstName]) }}">{{ Auth::user()->firstName }}</a></li>
....
```

Note closing `'` moved to after firstName array key.

That should at least fix the link

Comment: Well damn, yeah that fixed that! Annoying one little thing changes it. Still not completely working, for some reason I'm getting this error now "FatalErrorException in
8510057400a859f6c45b31b5a7b36172bf51341d.php line 3:
Call to undefined function getNameOrLocation()"

Comment: Yeah second pair eyes - ones that haven't gone quotation blind from staring at the same code for days - always helps. As for your new error it's same thing; you are missing a `>` before the model function in userblock.blade.php

Comment: I literally have gone quotation blind, where is the > missing I genuinely cant see it

Comment: Slowly unravelling the issues, that works now but another error now with "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getNameOrLocation()"

Comment: Ha. Easy one I think. Your function not defined in $users probably it's a collection. Laravel error a bit crap for this at it tries to use undefined function as a relationship so you get error regarding the builder rather than on your model class. Another typo perhaps?

Comment: its probably another damn typo

Comment: Success! yes you were correct! thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: No problems enjoyed the vicarious victory